# How do I get the filename with extension from the AWS S3 hosted file?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have large number of AWS S3 hosted files that do not show the file extensions. I need to upload these files to Wordpress via the API endpoint. The issue is that I am unable to upload the files without the extensions via the API. Is there a way to determine the AWS files with the extension? I tried something like this:

`curl -I https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/abc-def-xyz/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx?versionId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx`

This gave me the filename:

```
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="Test.jpg"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Server: AmazonS3
```

From the filename, is it possible to find the url with the extension?

I would like to find the url with extension something like this:
`https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/abc-def-xyz/Test.jpg` but this doesn't work.

I don't have access to the AWS account.

Comment: You can make HEAD request instead of GET first. This will reply to you with the HTTP headers mentioned by you. Then, by parsing the mime type (Content-Type header), you can guess the file extension.

Comment: If whoever uploaded the file provided some metadata, e.g. the Content-Type or the Content-Disposition you can use that to guess the actual file type. S3 does not care or know about file contents or file types.

Comment: Based on all of the Xs in the URL that you posted, my guess is that it's a file managed by some content repository. That name _is_ the file on S3;  you can't use `Test.jpg` to retrieve the file.

Comment: If you want to upload somewhere else, you'll need to download the file locally, look at the metadata/headers to get the name, and then rename and upload to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

This example is listed in the [Java V2 repository](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectContentType.java). Look at the logic and port it to the SDK you are using. This is single example, but you can get all objects and call this for each object.

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectcontenttype.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectcontenttype.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetObjectContentType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <bucketName> <keyName>>\n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket name. \n\n"+
            "    keyName - The key name. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        getContentType(s3,bucketName,keyName);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectcontenttype.main]
    public static void getContentType (S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName) {

        try {
            HeadObjectRequest objectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            HeadObjectResponse objectHead = s3.headObject(objectRequest);
            String type = objectHead.contentType();
            System.out.println("The object content type is "+type);

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectcontenttype.main]
}
```